# What is this critter?

Tags: houseplants

Can anyone please tell me what this critter is? My philodendron plant has brown spots on yellow leaves, and the leaves would very early on become shriveled, dried, and dead while blooming. I was throwing coffee grounds in the soil, which became molded! When scooping out the molded soil, I found this small critter and I have no idea what it is.  Please help!![image: ![**enter image description here**]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p9GaT.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

Looks like some sort of centipede. They are predators of other insects, so its presence might indicate you have an insect problem.

Comment: Wow!  That’s interesting!  Should I get rid of all of this soil and start from scratch and replace it with new soil or would that be too drastic for it to survive?

Answer (score 0):

House centipede. Beneficial hunter of house pests. Harmless to people.